# Moving Data From SQL Server To Oracle -- Character vs Bytes

Tags: sql, oracle, byte

I am in the process of moving data from SQL Server to Oracle.  I am having to do this using C# code we have written.  (Long story but has to do with corporate standards, so no SSIS or other utilities allowed)

The question I have is when I have a field that is NVARCHAR(200) on SQL Server and in oracle it is NVARCHAR(200).  I understand that on Oracle the 200 represents 200 bytes.  My question is how can I move data from the SQL Server where the field has all 200 characters populated.  The problem is that the 200 character in SQL Server is more than 200 bytes.

In the process I am reading the data form SQL Server, storing it into a string array, and then using Array Binding (Oracle Data Access) to push the data to Oracle.  It all works fine, however, when I have a field that is fully populated in SQL Server it has more than the max allowed bytes for the same field definition in Oracle.

Is there an easy way to check the byte size of the string from SQL Server and see if it is more than 200 bytes, and if so, truncate it so that only 200 bytes are moved across?  (For what I am doing, truncation of the data is ok)

Comment: NVARCHAR2(200) in Oracle should be 200 *characters*. The docs state when specifying NVARCHAR2(*size*): "Variable-length Unicode character string having maximum length *size* **characters**. The number of bytes can be up to two times size for AL16UTF16 encoding and three times size for UTF8 encoding." So according to the Oracle docs you have no problem. Have you observed a problem? Do you get an error?

Comment: Oh, one other thing. Have you looked at the BulkCopy methods of the Oracle Data Provider in C#? I have had success using those to transfer data into Oracle from any DataReader without manually binding. Makes it a bit easier as you can leave it to the methods to figure out how to bind as long as the datatypes on either side is compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I understand that on Oracle the 200 represents 200 bytes.*

That is true for `VARCHAR` but not for `NVARCHAR`

[Quote from the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020)

> *The NVARCHAR2 data type is a Unicode-only data type. When you create a table with an NVARCHAR2 column, you supply the maximum number of **characters** it can hold. [...] Width specifications of character data type NVARCHAR2 **refer to the number of characters**.*

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

So for `NVARCHAR` you should be fine.

For `VARCHAR2` you *can* indeed specify the length in bytes or characters - but even there the number denotes the *default* setting which can be changed anytime.

Comment: THANK you so much... This solved my issue.. The issue i was having was the field that was causing the issue was a VARCHAR2 with a max of 200 bytes.   By changing this to NVARCHAR2 with a max of 200 char we are ok..

Comment: You could also have defined that as `VARCHAR2(200 Char)` to get 200 characters